# Bolt CMS: Taxonomy listings, Pagination and Listing records

Tags: php, pagination, bolt-cms

trying to get myself familiar with Bolt CMS, I successfully installed it, as well as the Lorem Ipsum demo content and I noticed the following:

1/ According to v2.0.0's changelog: Fix the pager for taxonomy-listings and Paging now works correctly for taxonomy-listings. Reducing the listing_records directive to 2 in config.yml, to force the default pagination, then visiting /categories/books url, I get the correct pagination with wrong results (namely, I never get the first and last result of my 4 books, only the two inner for both pages). Am I missing something?

2/ Is there a priority precedence between config.yml's and contenttypes.yml's listing_records directive?

Thanks in advance,

Comment: Your first question might be better suited for a bugreport in github - if it is still an issue

Answer (score 0):

The second part of your question about precedence:

The value in the global config.yml are used as a default/fallback if the settings in contenttypes.yml are absent..

So the settings in contenttypes.yml will override the settings in config.yml